# Writing Driver for Mipi csi-2 Camera

Tags: linux-kernel, camera, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I need to write the camera driver which is for imx290 in Linux. I make some research and found out that I need to make changes or to add new v4l2-subdev for the camera . I am new about writing driver and etc. I need recommendation and advice about which specific properties should I have to check while writing MIPI csi-2 camera driver or which properties are important for camera reliability for the target device. My target device has i.MX6Q processor (Wandboard Quad).

Thanks a lot for your help.

Sincerely

Must_ba

Comment: Check *drivers/media/platform/* folder for existing examples.

Comment: @0andriy I have updated this question I am triyng to probe he driver but I have faced with other problem , csi_mclk I have posted it as a new question   Can you look at it , I need some advice  Thanks. This is the new post link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127039/mipi-csi2-error-could-not-get-clock-csi-mclk